# Formal neighborhood of isolated singularity via DAG

Tags: reference-request, deformation-theory, singularity-theory, derived-algebraic-geometry

I work over a field of characteristic $0$, denoted $k$. Let $f:\mathbf{A}^{d+1}\rightarrow\mathbf{A}^{1}$ have an isolated singularity at $0$, and let $\widehat{Z}$ denote the formal neighborhood of $0$ in $Z:=Z(f)$. Then, by now quite well known, results of Lurie and Pridham describe $\widehat{Z}$ in terms of a derived Lie algebra structure on $\mathbb{T}_{0}[-1]Z$, where $\mathbf{T}Z$ denotes the tangent complex of $Z$ at $0$. We can model derived Lie algebras more strictly via $\mathcal{L}_{\infty}$-algebras. Such is the data of a graded vector space $\mathcal{L}$, together with a family of *brackets* $$l_{n}:\bigwedge^{n}\mathcal{L}\rightarrow\mathcal{L}[2-n]$$ satisfying a bunch of axioms. $l_{1}$ is a differential, $l_{2}$ is almost a Lie bracket with $l_{3}$ homotopically trivializing the failure of the Jacobi identity etc.

Writing $V$ for the tangent space to $\mathbf{A}^{d+1}$ at $0$, $\mathbb{T}_{0}[-1]Z$ is isomorphic as a complex to $V[-1]\oplus k[-2]$ with trivial differential. A little check implies the brackets can only have non-trivial components mapping $S^{j}V$ to $k$, noting that $V$ lives in odd degree here so we end up with symmetric powers. The only conceivable guess for such brackets is to take the graded components of the Taylor expansion around $0$. In particular the second component $l_{2}$ is given by the Hessian. I presume that this is a standard fact and my **question** is a request for a reference for it.

Comment: Mike Artin’s Tata notes.

Comment: Since the functor's (derived) representable, the result in this case doesn't need to invoke that theorem. It amounts to asking for an $L_{\infty}$ algebra $L$ Koszul dual to the formal completion of the quasi-free cdga $k[x_0,\ldots,x_d, t]~:~ \delta t= f$, with $t$ in chain degree $1$. Choosing $L$ to be dual to the span of the $x_i,t$ gives  the desired description tautologically.